# how to access data from service to ts file in angular

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

```
this.http.post('',dataform).subscribe((res)=>
      console.log('response data',res),
      (err)=>console.log(err)
    );
```

I can get the response in service but is there any way we can access data in app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

In the service, only have

```
sendData(dataform: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('',dataform)
}
```

and in the app.component use that method to call

```
response: any;
myMethod(): void {
  this.service.sendData(myDataForm).subscribe(res => {
    this.response = res;
  })
}
```

Ideally you can replace the 'any' types with something more meaningful.